# jquery autocomplete with ajax complete guide

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-autocomplete

can someone please explain me a working example of J-Query auto-complete with ajax.
i need it to put it on my website but have no idea of it.i have tried J-Query website but that explanations were not useful.

Answer (score 2):

Try this tutorial: http://www.pontikis.net/blog/jquery-ui-autocomplete-step-by-step

In the future try google what you need and after post to stackoverflow.
I googled for "jquery autocomplete ajax example" ;-)